# Generate random numbers from poisson distribution

Tags: random, poisson

I want to generate 60 random numbers from a poisson distribution with a mean of `M = 4` and a range of `min = 2` `max = 9`. Does anybody know how to solve this (preferably in Matlab?).

Best!

Comment: Draw uniform numbers in [0, 1) and use that as the input to a quantile function associated with the poisson with mean 4. Reject numbers out of your range.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Statistics toolbox, you can use `poissrnd`...

Comment: Yes, I used lambda = 4; poissrnd(lambda, 60); but here, I cannot specify a range...

Comment: @Ramzi, no self-respecting library would offer a range function as it completely ruins the generator. You'll need to do that bit yourself. +1 for the answer.

Comment: I see! So I have to let Matlab generate the numbers and then select (post hoc) only those values that are in the range of interest? Okay, seems plausible.